# Are there any sports that are meant to be played in the rain?

Tags: water-sports

Is there any sport where rain is either required for the sport or enhances the sport? I'm looking for answers about sports anywhere in the world.

Comment: Does the rain have to occur _during_ the sport itself? If not, any outdoor watersports because you need rain to get the lake...

Comment: @PhilipKendall What do you mean by "you need rain to get to the lake"?

Comment: Read my comment more carefully :-) - you need rain to _make_ the lake in the first place, or all you've got is some soil.

Comment: @PhilipKendall LOL! Sorry, but I am looking for the rain to occur during the sport.

Comment: @PhilipKendall : what is your object to Worm Charming as a sport? Rain does affect the outcome so it answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but field hockey is often played on watered turf which requires to be wet. You don't need rain, but watching it is as if the turf was wet due to light rain.

Comment: Rain is neither required for field hockey, nor does it enhance the sport (except in very specific circumstances where the turf is a water or wet dress, has not been watered recently, and cannot be artificially watered because of drought or water availability conditions). This does not answer the question in a helpful or meaningful way.

Comment: Couple of things: I did start my answer with "Not exactly what you're asking for". But more importantly, the field DOES require water. The water based fields are the most common type of filed nowadays (at least for important tournaments), and these fields require to be wet.